# std::map, storing pointer (to object) by pointer (to some object's related struct). Which types to use?

Tags: c++, c, callback

To overcome the [impossibility](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2) of giving C library a callback to C++ member function, wanted to implement something like this:

```
SomeObject* findSomeObjectByHandlePointer(datahandle *dh) { }..
```

by using a map, which contains addresses of *datahandle as an index, and addresses of *SomeObject's as value.

When SomeObject is created, it produces a group of datahandle's, which are unique for the object. Then, it passes a pointer to *datahandle and static callback function to C library, then C library calls back and returns a pointer to datahandle, that in turn can be associated back with a SomeObject.

Which types can you recommend for storing pointer values in a map besides safe but slow `<string, SomeObject*>`?

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135560/pointer-to-value-in-a-stdmap/1135588#1135588) tells me to avoid using `auto_ptr` too.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't the callback receive a pointer to the object itself (converted to `void*`), avoiding the need for any kind of lookup?

Comment: How did `string` get involved?

Comment: I think you missed the first sentence in that article. **Don't.** ... if you must to support legacy code then you can create a global or singleton of your object and export methods as non-member functions at a top level.

Comment: @AJG85, currently, some method is available as non-member function. It can't distinguish, which instance (one of objects) should receive the callback. Due to this, I need to identify the callback->data and C++ object->data pair, to call the correct object's real callback function.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, not sure if storing pointers as a map index will not result in copying them.. need some concrete type for index, find and comparison.

Comment: @mhambra: Uhm.. if you copy a pointer, the stored address doesn't magically change. It's totally fine to have a `std::map<int*,some_type>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, C-like callbacks take a `void* user_data` parameter, which allows you to pass in anything you want:

```
void c_func(void (*fptr)(void*), void* user_data){
  // do some stuff
  fptr(user_data);
}
```

Now, simply make the following static member function:

```
class A{
public:
  static void c_callback(void* my_data){
    A* my_this = static_cast<A*>(my_data);
    // do stuff with my_this
  }
};
```

**Edit:** According to @Martin's comment, you may get unlucky with a static member function. Better use an `extern "C"` function:
extern "C" void c_callback(void* my_data){
  // same as static method
}
And pass that + your `A` instance to that `c_func`:

```
int main(){
  A a;
  c_func(&A::c_callback,&a);
}
```

Or if that `A` instance needs to outlive the current scope, you need to somehow save the heap-allocated pointer somewhere and delete it manually later on. A `shared_ptr` or the likes won't work here, sadly. :(

---

On your problem of storing pointer in a map, that's not a problem at all, see this little [example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/lncpq).

Comment: Rather than `// do stuff with my_this`, you could do `my_this->callback()`, and do all the work in a normal member function.

Comment: @Mike: That's included in `do stuff`. ;) Just like normal behaviour is included in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Technically static methods have C++ calling convention. C functions (in a C library) can only use C calling conventions. You are getting lucky that they overlap on your system. It is best to declare a extern "C" function rather than a static method.

Comment: @Martin: Really? I didn't know. I thought static methods just get a cdecl convention and are then done with it, but maybe that's just another Microsoft thingy. Thanks for the hint, will edit it in.

Comment: @Xeo .. okay, will try this. But currently, still need to somehow store that pointer-pointer relation before trying to fight callbacks again..

Answer (score 1):

I think this will suffice.  It is what we use:

```
class datahandle;
class SomeObject;

typedef std::map<datahandle*, SomeObject*> pointer_map;

pointer_map my_map;

SomeObject* findSomeObjectByHandlePointer( datahandle *dh) {
    pointer_map::const_iterator ff = my_map.find(dh);
    if (ff != my_map.end()) {
        return ii->second;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: datahandle is a struct.. aren't there a kind of copy/compare value problems when using struct* as map index?

Answer (score 1):

Often callback functions have an extra parameter of type `void*` which you can use to pass in any additional data you might need. So if you want to use a member function as your callback, you pass in a pointer to the object casted to `void*` and then cast it back and call the member function in your callback function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many reads and less writes, you could use vector as a set. It is very common, because `lower_bound` is more effective than `map` and use less space from memory:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string,Your_pointer> your_type;
bool your_less_function( const your_type &a, const your_type &b )
{
  // your less function
  return ( a < b );
}
...
std::vector<your_type> ordered-vector;
```

When you add values:

```
...
ordered-vector.push_back(value)
...
// Finally. The vector must be sorted before read.
std::sort( ordered-vector.begin(), ordered-vector.end(), your_less_function );
```

When ask for data:

```
std::vector<your_type>::iterator iter = std::lower_bound( ordered-vector.begin(), ordered-vector.end(), value, your_less_function );
if ( ( iter == ordered-vector.end() ) || your_less_function( *iter, value ) )
  // you did not find the value
else
  // iter contains the value
```